# Struts problem -- s:hidden

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el

I have the following code in my JSP.  I'm using a Struts form where I'm passing in a List that I'm iterating over, and each item in the List has its own separate form.  All fields in the list are Strings except for id, which is an int.  I'm trying to render the int in a s:hidden tag, but Eclipse is telling me, "Invalid attribute (value)."  The Struts documentation says that value takes a String, but I'm wrapping bulletins.id inside ${...}, which should convert it into a String.  I've done multiple Google searches to try to resolve this issue, but I've come up with nothing.  Has anyone seen this before?

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@ page language="java" import="model.Bulletin"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

    <!-- Some more code here that's not relevant to this problem -->

    <c:forEach var="bulletins" items="${bulletins}">
        <c:if test="${bulletins.approved == false}">
            <s:form action="ApproveBulletin" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><b>From:</b> <c:out value="${bulletins.name}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><b>Subject:</b> <c:out value="${bulletins.subject}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><b>Date:</b> <c:out value="${bulletins.date}" /> <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><c:out value="${bulletins.note}" />
<!-- Error here -->         <s:hidden name="id" value="${bulletins.id}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:submit type="button" value="approve" label="Approve"
                            action="ApproveBuletin" /></td>
                        <td><s:submit type="button" value="deny" label="Deny"
                            action="DenyBulletin" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </s:form>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>

    <!-- Some more code here that's not relevant to this problem -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 tags prefer OGNL so replace ${} with %{} or even better just write

```
<s:hidden name="id" value="bulletins.id" />
```

This is personal preference but I'd write that page with only S2 tags as such:

```
<s:iterator value="bulletins">
    <s:if test="approved == false">
        <s:form action="ApproveBulletin" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b>From:</b> 
                        <s:property value="name" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><b>Subject:</b> <s:property value="subject" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><b>Date:</b> <s:property value="date" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                            <s:property value="note"/>
                            <s:hidden name="id" value="id" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><s:submit type="button" value="approve" label="Approve" action="ApproveBuletin" /></td>
                    <td><s:submit type="button" value="deny" label="Deny" action="DenyBulletin" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
        </s:form>
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

There is very little difference. Note that the iterator stack pushes the current object being iterated onto the stack so you don't need dot notation inside the iterator element (well for more deeply nested objects you would...).

Comment: This solution got rid of the error on the hidden field, but now nothing is appearing on screen, even though I have verified that there are items in the List where approved == false.  In previous tests where I had hard-coded a String value for hidden, the List items were appearing, but they are not showing up now with the rewrite.  Is this something I need a new thread for, or can I get help for this here?

Comment: If you provide an Action class with hard coded data I'll help you with a JSP which produces what you're looking for... never mind I see you've started an other question. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have no utter idea about the Struts2 part, but the following is definitely wrong:

```
<c:forEach var="bulletins" items="${bulletins}">
```

You're overwriting the list with the currently iterated item. In normal Java terms, you're basically doing:

```
for (Bulletin bulletins : bulletins) {}
```

This makes no sense and also wouldn't compile (*duplicate local variable* or something like that).

Give it a different and unique name. `bulletin` would make the most sense. There's means of only one bulletin inside the loop, right?

```
<c:forEach var="bulletin" items="${bulletins}">
```

and then replace any `${bulletins.property}` inside the loop by `${bulletin.property}`.